# How to pass variable value in create database statement?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlyog

enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umn6B.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umn6B.png)I am trying to pass variable value in create database statement using SET variable. And then trying execute that statement using PREPARE which throws an error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
SET @dbname := 'mydb';
SET @query := CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE `', @dbname, '`');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @query;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Error:**

```
1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: PREPARE stmt_1 from @query

Error Code: 1295
This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet
```

MySQL Version:
[image]

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.80, for Win64 (unknown)